# Pass multiple data without using navpush

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to implement a shopping cart system for my ionic application.

When i click on the button "add to cart" i want to see the product added in the basket.
I don't know how to pass my data to the basket page.

example data to pass

```
name: any;
price: any;
```

My function

```
public addToBasket(): void {
    //data for the tabBadge value
    this.event.publish("cart:updated", this.count);

    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

Is it possible to use event to pass multiple data to another page without using navpush?

Comment: You can use angular services : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly and they certainly shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting data and delegate data access to a service.
Services are a great way to share information among classes that don't know each other.
You can find out more at : [Services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#services)